# Is 'still wasn't able to' correct in this context?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Kindly, consider the following situation:

The question says:
***Complete the following with was / wasn’t able to.***

The context says:
A man said: ‘In my garden, there is a heavy stone, I tried to lift it many times when I was young, but I couldn’t move it. And when I grew old, I **still wasn’t able to** lift it. Nothing has changed!’

Is this use of **'still wasn't able to'** correct? Shouldn't the context be: 'still unable to'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**I still wasn't able to lift it** and **I still was unable to lift it** are equivalent.

Stylistically, some might prefer matching the form used in the previous sentence, but there is nothing ungrammatical about either construction.

Comment: I'll note in passing that “was still unable” is also valid, but “wasn't still able” would mean the speaker was *formerly* able.